# Drupal form_set_cache Too Slow

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I am running a drupal commerce site, where the first request of the site is taking around 3 seconds to load. Its too high. on profiling i found out its because form_set_cache is taking around 2.5 Seconds to insert.

How to solve this, i read that it is not prescribed to move form_set_cache to memcache also since it is not static, how we can improve this.